# Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid "Failed to resolve assembly" using azure Devops

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-devops

I am developing small Xamarin forms application in visual studio 2022, I trying to implement Xamarin.Form.Datagrid, Everything working fine in visual studio but I am trying to run pipeline in azure Devops While I am getting error `Error : Failed to resolve assembly: Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid`, Please give me solution to resolve above issue.

Below I have added code

xmlns:dg="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid"

```
       <dg:DataGrid Grid.Row="0" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Report}"
                          SelectionEnabled="False"
                          RowHeight="45" HeaderHeight="45">   
           <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
               <dg:ColumnCollection> 
                     <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Name" PropertyName="Name" Width="150">
                           <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                               <DataTemplate>
                                   <ContentView>
                                       <Label  Text="{Binding Name}">
                                   </ContentView>
                               </DataTemplate>
                           </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                       </dg:DataGridColumn>
               </dg:ColumnCollection>
           </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
       </dg:DataGrid>
```

Comment: does your pipeline successfully restore all Nuget packages?

Comment: That's what I am getting error while build nuget packages in pipeline, Sorry for late reply Jason

Comment: except this one, remaining all are restore successfully

Comment: It seems to be relevant to Nuget packages.Uninstall package and install it again via Nuget Package Manager might help.

Comment: I tried manytimes but it is not working